# Week of the month

Tags: shell, date

I am trying to get the week number of the month and this is what I am trying to do:

```
x=`date +"%V"`
echo "x is $x"
y=`date +"%V" -d $(date +"%Y%m01")`
echo "y is $y"
week_of_month=$((x-y))
echo "week_of_month is $week_of_month"
```

and this is what I get:

```
x is 38
y is 38
week_of_month is 0
```

But if my statment is working correctly the value of y should be 35 or so. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's working fine here... you might try `y=\`date +"%V" -d $(date +"%Y-%m-01")\``

Comment: Same, your exact code in bash and sh seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: While not perfect, the following is close:
http://serverfault.com/questions/383666/how-to-determine-number-of-week-of-the-month

Comment: What is your rule for defining a week number? Which calendar are you using (ISO, American, Islamic, ...)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on OS X:

```
week_today=$(date "+%W")
week_start_of_month=$(date -v1d "+%W")
week_of_month=$[week_today - week_start_of_month + 1]
```

This assumes Monday to be the first day of the week. If you want Sunday to be treated as the first day of the week instead you'd have to substitute `%W` with `%U`.

This gives a week number from 1 to 6. If you'd like to have a zero indexed week number instead just drop the `+ 1` in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trust `date +%V` because it gives the (apparently useless) ISO week of year.

This means you get odd-ball results, like Jan.1 being the 52nd week of the year.

**E.g.:**

```
date --date='2012-01-01 12pm UTC' +%V
52
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the most portable solution:

```
#/bin/sh

_DOM=`date +%d`
_WOM=$(((${_DOM}-1)/7+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, I was able to do this for the desired result.

```
y=`date -v1d +%V`
```

Comment: That gives the week of year of the first day of the month. Not the week of month as requested.

Comment: Yes, that gives the week of year of the first day of the month, since that was the one problem in the original poster's code.  You've extrapolated the rest, bravo!

Answer (score 0):

on Solaris 5.10

`date +%V` works fine.

refer to [man pages](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/date.1.php) of Date for your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a shell person, But if you want to find the week number an algorithm like this will do.

Find the offset , the date of the first sunday, for march 2012 it is 4.
(yourdate+offset)/7 will give you the week of month that it is.

you can easily do this in c# , dont know about shell.

Answer (score -1):

For Linux, try below command

```
Week=$(($(date "+%W")-$(date --date="$(date --date="$(($DAY-1)) days ago")" +"%V")+1))
```

This will calculate the current week number and subtract the week number of start date of the month.
Remove +1 at the end if you want to start the week number of the month from '0'.