# bash get week number of current month

Tags: bash, date

I want to get the week number of the current month in bash. I checked the `date` command, but there aren't any options for week-of-month, only week-of-year.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542466/week-of-the-month?

Comment: yes but that is for Mac and sadly none of these options work for me

Comment: Then try this *cal | awk -v date="`date +%d`" '{ for( i=1; i <= NF ; i++ ) if ($i==date) { print FNR-2} }'*

Comment: As a start: how do you count the weeks of the month? It could be `(day_of_month+6)/7` or something completely different.

Comment: @Jens - Tried that command line on Ubuntu 22.04 and nothing happened - returned with no output.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution working with AIX, but it works on any Unix

```
#!/bin/bash
year=$(date +'%Y')
month=$(date +'%m')
day=$(date +'%e' | tr -d '[:blank:]')

WEEKNUM=$(cal ${month} ${year} | grep -v "[[:alpha:]]" | grep -nw ${day} | cut -f1 -d':')
echo "WEEKNUM ${WEEKNUM}"
```

On Linux you can switch first day of the week to fit your needs

On AIX, first day of the week is inherited by locale

Comment: Nice!  Confirmed works on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
this_month=$(ncal -w | tail -1 | awk '{print NF}')
total_this_month=$(ncal -w | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')
this_week=$(date +%W)

this_monthweek=$(($this_week - $total_this_month + $this_month))

echo -e "today $(date +%d.%m) WEEK=$this_monthweek"
```

Hope, this is what you are looking for.

**Edit:**
A solution without ncal

```
this_month=$(date -d "20170501" +%V)
end_this_month=$(date -d "20170531" +%V)
total_this_month=$(($end_this_month - $this_month + 1))
this_week=$(date +%W)

this_monthweek=$(($this_week - $end_this_month + $total_this_month))

echo -e "today $(date +%d.%m) WEEK=$this_monthweek"
```

Comment: no it does not work, I get : this_month=0, total_this_mont=blank, this_week=21

Comment: May 2017
   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
18     1  2  3  4  5  6
19  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
20 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
22 28 29 30 31

Comment: unfortunately i can't see the format of your `ncal -w` output. Are the week numbers shown in the last row? The things to get the number you want are: the week number of the recent week; the number of total weeks by the end of the recent month and  the number of weeks of the recent month. For today this would be: 21;22;5. The calculation 21-22+5 gives you 4.

Comment: i am running this on quap and I only could install cal not ncal, does it work with cal to, because it only outputs the days of the month

Comment: i can get the current week with date +"%V", but i have no idea on how to get the week of the end of the month

Comment: does `cal -N -w` give you the week numbers in the bottom row?

Comment: i edited my answer and added a solution without `ncal`

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out, but I am not sure if it works for every month and week of the year, and I have not idea on how to manipulate the date to test it

```
current_week="$(date +%V)"
last_of_month="$(date --date "-"$(date +%d)" days +1 month" +%Y-%m-%d)"
last_of_month_week="$(date --date="${last_of_month}" +%V)"
week_number="$((${current_week} - ${last_of_month_week} + 5))"
```